# Can we have same id's for 2 elements?

Tags: html

```
<label id="lbl">abc</label>

<label id="lbl" class="disabled">bdb</label>
```

Even though it shouldn't have 2 or more same id elements but just wanna ask what if one of them is disabled,will it affect the performance when i call for #lbl?

Comment: Probably tryout with array of elements with `getElementsByTagName`...

Comment: disabled is only an attribute to an element. Even if you supply disabled on it then also its invalid because DOM has 2 duplicate elements that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**W3C** [Global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

> A unique identifier for the element.
>   There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

**Javascript**
I don't understand what you mean with `affect the performance`, but if you do a `getElementById`, you will get the first match.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/yupbf2zh/

Answer (score 0):

Id's has to be unique. If you want to use same , you can use class instead of id's. 
However, if you use same id, then first id will work.